# How do I show that the set of all almost convergent sequences of real numbers is nowhere dense in $l_\infty$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485888479),  Lorentz claimed that the set $\mathcal F$ of all [almost convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence) sequences is closed and non-separable in the normed linear space $l_\infty$ with respect to the sup-norm and I've understood the proof in my [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282690/the-set-of-all-almost-convergent-real-sequences-is-closed-and-non-separable-in).

Lorentz also claimed that $\mathcal F$ is nowhere dense in $l_\infty$.

**My Question :** How can I show that $\mathcal F$ is nowhere dense in $l_\infty?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{F}$ is closed, it is nowhere dense in $\ell^\infty$ if and only if it has empty interior in $\ell^\infty$.

Suppose not.

Then there is $x \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for $y \in \ell^\infty$, $\|x-y\|_\infty \leq \varepsilon$ implies that $y \in \mathcal{F}$. Take arbitrary $z \in \ell^\infty \setminus \mathcal{F}$ with $\|z\|_\infty = 1$. Then consider $y = x + \varepsilon z$. Since $\|x-y\|_\infty = \varepsilon \|z\|_\infty = \varepsilon$, we must have $y \in \mathcal{F}$. But $\mathcal{F}$ is a linear space so we then get that $z \in \mathcal{F}$ which is a contradiction.

---

Note that the above is really a proof of the fact that if $Y$ is a closed proper subspace of a normed space $X$ then $Y$ is nowhere dense in $X$.

Comment: Just as an addition to the general fact mentioned in the last paragraph, I will add the link to another post on this site: [Every proper subspace of a normed vector space has empty interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/148850).